# Pig versions and UDF

Tags: apache-pig

I am using pig version as 0.12,But for creating UDFs i am using the jar file of Pig 0.9 version. 
I simply downloaded the jar file for Pig 0.9 version and  added that in my eclipse classpath.
All the UDFs that I created  using  Pig 0.9 version API works fine.
But I would like to know the impact on that. 
Is there any problem that I will face in future

Comment: general suggestion - try using pig version 0.12 during runtime and see if UDF works fine.

Comment: yes . its works fine in cluster.  pig version n cluster is 0.12

Answer (score 0):

The issues that you will face is API inconsistencies as time goes by. Some of the core APIs are relatively stable. Heck, most. But the longer you use an old Pig API the higher the chance you'll get an issue running in the cluster.

Something else to think about is are you overriding your Pig version in the cluster. For example, say you have an uber-jar with the pig scripts in it. If that JAR contains Pig v.09, you'll actually use that version rather than .12. By not migrating, you might be pulling in the wrong version of Pig.